# Segmentation Fault before reaching main - C++

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior, string-literals

I'm writing a code to find a proper input that would generate a certain output for the SHA-1 hash function.

The problem I'm running into is that my code raises a segmentation fault, but `gdb` finds that it raises the following error upon entering `main()` and befor execution of any other code:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strncpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:636
636 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
```

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

#include "sha1.hpp"

int main() {
    char *prefix = "SHA1sha1";
    char *suffix = "chicken and beer";
    std::string hashvalue = "nonzero";
    char *line = "just some dummy string";
    int loop_number = 0;

    while (hashvalue.c_str()[0] != '0' || hashvalue.c_str()[1] != '0') {
        // change prefix
        strncpy(prefix, hashvalue.c_str(), 8);
        // hash the concatenated string of prefix and suffix
        strncpy(line, prefix, 8);
        strncat(line, suffix, strlen(suffix));
        hashvalue = sha1(line);

        loop_number++;
        if (loop_number % 1000 == 0) std::cout << loop_number << "th loop, hash value: " << hashvalue << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Found prefix: " << prefix << " with hash value: " << hashvalue << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The `sha1.hpp` was not implemented by me, but was taken from here: http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha1-function

I have changed `sha1.h` to `sha1.hpp`, though, but this is probably not what's causing the segmentation fault.

Now I *have*  tried searching for a solution to this problem with the error message and also with the keywords "segmentation fault before main", and this post seems to be going through similar problems: [Segmentation Fault before main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253267/segmentation-fault-before-main)

However, I have looked into the two suggested solutions, but couldn't find one that fits me.

1. I don't think my code has too many variables in the stack. In fact, I have tried commenting out using the function `sha1()` just in case, but the same problem occurred.
2. I have initialized all `char*` and `std::string` in my code before usage.

FYI, I'm using `g++` to compile my C++ codes.

Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't need to use any `char *` variables whatsoever.  Everything can be `std::string`, and thus be much safer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie is right, you should be *very* circumspect about C++ code that uses legacy C strings. Not that you *can't,* just that it's rarely a good idea if you're coding C++ exclusively.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for the heads up, but the answers below (which I'm still trying to process in my head) say that string literals cannot be modified. It seems like legacy C strings are easier to code with but unsafe...? (I know they're unsafe, since I've had far too many faults by using them. I just want to know I'm on the right page here)

Comment: C-style strings are harder to work with, not easier!  You have to manage their lifetimes and capacities, which you don't with `std::string`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Oh, sorry. I got confused. I thought string literals were std::string, but it was the other way around... Thanks!

Comment: If you had turned on your compiler warnings, the compiler itself would have pointed out the mistakes in the code.

Comment: @Eljay Actually, I did have them on... But I thought this type of warning could go without having to be dealt with.

Comment: `std::string`s can be indexed, so you can write `hashvalue[0]`.

Comment: "I thought this type of warning could go without having to be dealt with" - you don't have to *fix* them (they are warnings, after all) but you should *investigate* them at least :-) A good developer will try to remove warnings as well as errors, even if that means temporarily turning off the warning for a small section of code (that's hopefully proof that it's been investigated and deemed okay).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are modifying the immutable contents.

```
// change prefix
strncpy(prefix, hashvalue.c_str(), 8);
// hash the concatenated string of prefix and suffix
strncpy(line, prefix, 8);
strncat(line, suffix, strlen(suffix));
```

Try to change the declaration as below.

```
char prefix[100] = "SHA1sha1";
char suffix[200] = "chicken and beer";
char line[200] = "just some dummy string
```

---

Also, I guess

```
while (hashvalue.c_str()[0] != '0' || hashvalue.c_str()[1] != '0') {
```

should be

```
while (hashvalue.c_str()[0] != '0' && hashvalue.c_str()[1] != '0') {
```

**Update:**

De Morgan's law states,

```
not (A and B) = not A or not B
```

Again it is individual's choice to use whatever form they want

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But why do people think that the while-loop condition is written incorrectly? I'm trying to make it stop when the first two letters of hashvalue are 00.

Comment: I actually edited the last comment, could you recheck? Thanks.

Comment: as per De Morgan's law it is `not (A and B) = not A or not B`. Again it is individual's choice to use whatever form they want. @정진하

Answer (score 4):

String literals have types of constant character arrays in C++, and any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior.  You are trying to modify a string literal at least in this statement:

```
strncpy(prefix, hashvalue.c_str(), 8);
```

Instead of string literals you should use character arrays or objects of the type `std::string`.

Pay attention to that; for example this `if` statement

```
while (hashvalue.c_str()[0] != '0' || hashvalue.c_str()[1] != '0') {
```

could be written much simpler:

```
while (hashvalue[0] != '0' || hashvalue[1] != '0') {
```

though it seems the condition does not make sense. Maybe you mean the following

```
while ( hashvalue.size() > 1 ) {
```

Also you need to include the header `<string>`

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: For the part about the condition being weird, that's not the case. But thanks for the answer! It really helped.

Comment: You state that modifying a string literal is UB. However, I think for this program to have UB it doesn't even have to do that. `prefix` and others not being `const` in itself is UB if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Chipster Declaring a pointer to a string literal without the qualifier const per se is not undefined behavior though the Standard does not allow this. A compiler can allow this for the backward compatibility.