# Why so much boilerplate for iostream in assembly output?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly

For the following code:

```
int main()
{
}
```

For `g++ -pedantic -Wall -O3 -S -o test.asm test.cpp && cat test.asm`, the assembly output is unsurprisingly clean. If I do `gcc -x c ... test c` with `#include <stdio.h>` at the top, the output is **identical** except for the label names. Actually it doesn't matter if it's in `C++` or `C` mode. Other headers like `<string>`, `<vector>`, `<algorithm>`, `<ostream>` etc. give identical results.

```
    .file   "test.cpp"
    .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
.LCOLDB0:
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
.LHOTB0:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE0:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE0:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.9.0 20131223 (experimental)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

But as soon as you add `#include <iostream>`, it blows up (identical part omitted):

```
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE0:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE0:
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDB1:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTB1:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB1027:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %edi
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    movl    $__dso_handle, %edx
    movl    $_ZStL8__ioinit, %esi
    movl    $_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev, %edi
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    jmp __cxa_atexit
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1027:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .text.unlikely
.LCOLDE1:
    .section    .text.startup
.LHOTE1:
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align 8
    .quad   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,1
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.9.0 20131223 (experimental)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

What makes `<iostream>` special?

One quote that might be relevant is:

> In terms of static initialization order, cout is guaranteed to be
>   properly constructed and initialized no later than the first time an
>   object of type ios_base::Init is constructed, with the inclusion of
>    counting as at least one initialization of such objects
>   with static duration.

Comment: I wonder if you'd get the same results with `<ostream>`, if you actually instantiated and used a stream.

Comment: Doesn't your quote answer your question?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yeah I guess it does, but I didn't realize why until I googled it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [MSDN forum link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/637a4c27-3e30-4b88-b36d-b5b720cf0d04/why-are-cout-cin-initialized-once-and-only-once-given-the-scheme-below-in-the-iostream?forum=vclanguage) provides a code snippet:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>

namespace std
{
    extern istream cin;
    extern ostream cout;
    ....

    // this is explained below
    static ios_base::Init __foo;    // not its real name
}
```

Relevant quote:

> Now, the runtime penalty mentioned previously: the global objects must
>   be initialized before any of your own code uses them; this is
>   guaranteed by the standard. Like any other global object, they must be
>   initialized once and only once. This is typically done with a
>   construct like the one above, and the nested class ios_base::Init is
>   specified in the standard for just this reason.

And the [standard quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8784923/1508519):

> According to §27.3/2: "The objects [std::cin, std::cout, etc.] are
>   constructed, and the associations are established at some time prior
>   to or during first time an object of class ios_base::Init is
>   constructed, and in any case before the body of main begins
>   execution."

The culprit is indeed the `ios_base::Init` line, as [cHao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779400/why-so-much-boilerplate-for-iostream-in-assembly-output#comment31146931_20779400)'s comment suggests. So if the msdn link is correct, then that means that `<iostream>` is [special](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb239d23df36a638) for that reason.