# Write a program that has an empty main but prints "hello there!" on the screen

Tags: c++

Hello I've been asked to write a C++ program with an empty main function body but the program should print: `"hi there!"`.

So I've done it this way:

```
#include <iostream>


struct Foo
{
    Foo(){std::cout << "hi there!\n";}
}fobj;

int bar()
{
    std::cout << "hi there!\n";
    return 0; // arbitrary value
}

int x{bar()};
double pi = (std::cout << "hi there!\n", 3.14);



int main()
{

}
```

The output:

```
hi there!
hi there!
hi there!
```

It looks it works fine from my codeblocks but on my phone using "Coding C++" it says: `process terminated. signal 11`.

- So is all my case are well-defined or there's something disastrous? Thank you.

Comment: Does your phone environment do the right thing for `std::cout` used inside of `main()` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Sure.

Comment: It's probably the **Static Initialization Order Fiasco**; take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/36563223/103167 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/8784892/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt: But that problem maybe occur only in header files where an object is initialized  from the other. isn't it?

Comment: Here you have a static object `Foo fobj` and another one `std::ostream std::cout`, which is initialized first?

Comment: In C++11, `std::cout` (and other standard streams) is guaranteed to be initialised before other objects of static storage duration.   Before that, `std::cout` is only guaranteed to be initialised at the start of `main()`, and the order of initialisation of `std::cout` relative to other objects of static storage duration is unspecified.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784892/is-stdcout-guaranteed-to-be-initialized) for the details about @Peter's comment.

Comment: @Peter Looks like an _answer_.

Comment: There's a pre-C++11 workaround: [`std::ios_base::Init`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785008/15416)