# C++ global variable in namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have seen a lot of questions on this, but none include explanation on how to compile the code for this specific use case. I run the following command: `g++ main.cpp c.cpp testobj.cpp -o main`, but running this gives me a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. When I have the print statement in the `main` method in `main.cpp` and remove all `TestObj` code it does work.

Is this the proper way of assigning the `C::test` constant?

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "c.h"
#include "testobj.h"

TestObj testobj;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

**c.h:**

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS
#define CONSTANTS

#include <string>

namespace C {
    extern std::string test;
}
#endif
```

**c.cpp:**

```
#include "c.h"

namespace C {
    std::string test = "test";
}
```

**testobj.h:**

```
#ifndef TESTOBJ
#define TESTOBJ

class TestObj {
public:
    TestObj();
};

#endif
```

**testobj.cpp:**

```
#include "testobj.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "c.h"

TestObj::TestObj() {
    std::cout << C::test << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the order of initialization for global variables within a single [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) is well defined, the order between translation units is *not*.

So if the `testobj` object in the `main.cpp` source file is initialized before the `C::test` object, then you will have weird behavior indeed.

If you have multiple translation units, each with global variables, then you can't rely on the initialization order between them.

Comment: I it save to change the declaration of `TestObj testobj` to `TestObj *testobj` and move the initialization to the `main()` method, by doing `*testobj = TestObj()`?

Comment: @martijnn2008 Yes, if you consider using pointers safe. :) The `main` function will always be called after all global variables have been initialized.

Answer (score 5):

This is caused by the initialization order of global static variables. It is undefined and is known as [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order). When `TestObj::TestObj(` uses `C::test` - it is not yet constructed.

The common way to solve it is to move the global static variable into a function local static variable,ie:

```
const std::string getTestString() {
    static std::string test = "test";
    return test;
}
```

now, when you call `getTestString()` test variable will be constructed, and it will be done exactly once. Also since C++11 initialization of static variables in functions is guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: Moreover, using std::cout in constructor of static variable is unsafe, because std::cout itself is static variable, and we also rely on its initialization.

Comment: @IgorSemenov I didnt think about it, since C++11 it looks like it was fixed - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784892/is-stdcout-guaranteed-to-be-initialized