# Variable templates and std::cout -- order of construction

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

It looks like we can safely use `std::cout` object in constructors of objects with static storage duration as stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784892/is-stdcout-guaranteed-to-be-initialized).

However, I'm not entirely sure that we can safely use them in case of variable templates:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
T x = T{};

void foo()
{
    class Test
    {
    public:
        Test() { std::cout << "Test::Test\n"; }
    };

    Test t = x<Test>;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "main\n";
}
```

This code crashes in clang ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c20353f4224bfb7b)) and I'm not sure whether it's a bug or not.

Comment: Works with GCC. Maybe it's a bug in clang?

Comment: @Cornstalks Maybe. But maybe it's just an unspecified behavior?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As explained in that question, one effect of

```
#include <iostream>
```

is the equivalent of defining a global variable

```
static std::ios_base::Init __init;
```

which (assuming that you include it at the start of the TU) guarantees that for all static storage duration objects with *ordered* initialization in the same TU, the stream objects have been set up.

However, explicitly and implicitly instantiated template specializations have *unordered* initialization ([[basic.start.dynamic]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic#1))<sup>1</sup>:

> Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage
>   duration is unordered if the variable is an implicitly or explicitly
>   instantiated specialization, and otherwise is ordered [*note omitted*]. Variables with ordered initialization defined within a single translation unit shall be initialized in the order of their definitions in the translation unit.

And since

> If a program starts a thread, the subsequent unordered initialization
>   of a variable is unsequenced with respect to every other dynamic
>   initialization. Otherwise, the unordered initialization of a variable
>   is indeterminately sequenced with respect to every other dynamic
>   initialization.

there's no guarantee that the stream objects have been initialized at the time  the variable template specialization `x<Test>` is initialized.

In this case, as one of the possible executions results in undefined behavior (using the stream objects before they are initialized), the behavior of the entire program is undefined (see [[intro.execution]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#5)).

The fix is to construct a `std::ios_base::Init` object yourself in `Test`'s constructor.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is actually underspecified for variable templates when C++14 was published, but it's always been the intent.</sub>

Comment: So they have unordered initialization even for those objects which are defined in the same translation unit?

Comment: @FrozenHeart Yes. There's no ordering among different TUs anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The next question then -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706549/stdcout-usage-in-constructors-of-objects-with-static-storage-duration