# std::cout usage in constructors of objects with static storage duration

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++03, c++98

Is it safe to use `std::cout` in constructors of objects with statc storage duration in C++98 / C++03?

It seems from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785008/1608835) that it isn't but it doesn't include any quotes from the standard.

Is it only safe to do that in C++11 and C++14?

Comment: safe or not, simply why?!

Comment: @David Haim Why what? Why do I want to use `std::cout` in such objects?

Comment: inside the constructor..

Comment: @DavidHaim, never heard of priniting out inside the constructor???

Comment: in an object with static storage duration? nope.

Comment: @DavidHaim As a poor man's startup loging system, or just a debugging facility, why not? Also, actually "why" is just another question, and has nothing to do with "is it safe to".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From C++14 (N3797), §27.4p2:

> The objects are constructed and the associations are established at some time prior to or during the first
>   time an object of class ios_base::Init is constructed, and in any case before the body of main begins exe-
>   cution.295 The objects are not destroyed during program execution.296 The results of including 
>   in a translation unit shall be as if  defined an instance of ios_base::Init with static storage
>   duration. Similarly, the entire program shall behave as if there were at least one instance of ios_base::Init
>   with static storage duration.

C++98 uses similar terminology, but without the "as if" clause.

Basically, what this *forbids* is using the following before `main`:

```
#include <ostream>
extern std::ostream cout;
```

Comment: And what about C++98 / C++03?

Comment: So it has the same behavior in all C++ standards and I'm perfectly safe to use `std::cout` in such objects, right?

Comment: There's a chain of DRs, starting from [LWG 369](http://wg21.link/LWG369), and ending at [LWG1123](http://wg21.link/LWG1123) that changed this between C++98 and C++11. While this might be fine in practice, claiming that the standard text in C++98 and C++03 supports this is misleading at best.

Comment: And the code claimed to be forbidden by this paragraph (assuming that you actually meant to put `cout` in `std`) is in fact already forbidden by the rule that you can't add declarations to `std` unless otherwise specified.

Comment: @T.C. As if that ever stopped anybody.