# About std::cout, why use "extern" rether than "singleton pattern"

Tags: c++, iostream, effective-c++

I read *effective C++* which item 04 mentioned

> Avoid  initialization  order  problems  across  translation  units  by  re-placing non-local static objects with local static objects.

I think that "global and only-one object" should be singleton pattern, not extern object after I read this item.

such as I/O object(std::cout)

But std::cout seems extern object.
(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/)

I am confused about this.

### edit: add code

I Capture some code form this book.

First is bad code:

```cpp
class FileSystem {
// from your library’s header file
public:
 ...std::size_t numDisks( ) const;
// one of many member functions...
}; 
extern FileSystem tfs;
```

> the  relative  order  of  initialization  of  non-local  staticobjects  defined  in  different  translation  units  is  undefined.

So abovementioned code may be fault when I call tfs.

Because tfs may not complete initialization.

The recommand code:

```
class FileSystem { ... }; // as before
FileSystem& tfs()
{
  static FileSystem fs;
  return fs;
}
class Directory { ... };// as beforeDirectory::Directory( params )
Directory::Directory( params ) // as before, except references to tfs are 
                               //now to tfs( )
{
...
std::size_t disks = tfs().numDisks( );
...
}
Directory& tempDir()
{
  static Directory td(params);
  return td;
}
```

Comment: Because C++ was modeled after C, which has global `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` variables.

Comment: why use "singleton" when you can use "extern"

Comment: btw, initialization order problems would (almost) not occurs to `std::cout`.

Comment: Related readings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784892/is-stdcout-guaranteed-to-be-initialized https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `extern` variable allows the (subjectively) nicer syntax of

```
std::cout << stuff;
```

Emphasizing that the standard stream is a unique object and not the result of some function call. Since streaming is meant to be done into stream objects, using object notation ties better into it.

As for the static initialization order fiasco, the standard library avoids it by using the [Schwarz Counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) technique for initialization. Initialization happens in a well defined order because including `iostream` adds a special global object of type [`Init`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init) to the including TU. The object's constructor handles the initialization of the stream before its first use, wherever that first use may be.

Comment: Thanks! The keyword looking likes "Schwarz Counter"

Answer (score 0):

Because C++ opted for a more elaborate approach, getting the efficiency and simplicity of direct object access and still avoiding the static initialization order fiasco.

How?

The c++ standard streams are not actually initialized statically. Instead, #include-ing [`<iostream>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream) defines a global static object of type [`std::ios_base::Init`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init), which manages a global reference-count, and with it the initialization of the C++ streams.

Or at least, that's how it is specified, but there is always the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).