# Using cout in the constructor of a class that is included in another class as a static member

Tags: c++, clang, language-lawyer, initialization-order

Following code

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B {
    static inline A a;
};

int main() {
}
```

succeeds after compiling with gcc, but crashes with segmentation fault after compiling with clang. Is the code not standard or is clang wrong?

https://godbolt.org/z/tEvfrW

Comment: The `MVCC` result is same as that of `GCC`. Something odd with how `clang` processes `static inline A a;`? Also, I think [copy-elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) will play a part in this (I may be wrong on this one though...)

Comment: @molbdnilo, I guess we have [stronger guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init): *The header `<iostream>` behaves as if it defines (directly or indirectly) an instance of `std::ios_base::Init` with static storage duration: this makes it safe to access the standard I/O streams in the constructors and destructors of static objects with ordered initialization (as long as `#include <iostream>` is included in the translation unit before these objects were defined).* If we make `B::a` not `inline`, it works.

Comment: What is the meaning of inlining an object?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 c++17 feature

Comment: Which version of Clang does it crash with?  It works fine with `Apple clang version 11.0.0`.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Making a variable inline means the same as for functions – its definition can exist in more than one translation unit, and must exist in every translation unit where it is odr-used. It is meaningless in this example, except for exposing an apparent bug in some versions of clang.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, for example, `clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cppreference on `std::ios_base::Init` [reads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init):

> The header `<iostream>` behaves as if it defines (directly or indirectly) an instance of `std::ios_base::Init` with static storage duration: this makes it safe to access the standard I/O streams in the constructors and destructors of static objects with **ordered initialization** (as long as `#include <iostream>` is included in the translation unit before these objects were defined).

You do include `<iostream>` before `B::a`, but the initialization of `B::a` (with `B::a` being `static inline` variable) is not part of [ordered initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables), so it can be initialized before `std::ios_base::Init`. It seems that Clang (some versions, at least) does exactly this. This is a valid behaviour.

The standard reads ([[basic.start.dynamic]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic)):

> 1. Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is unordered if the variable is an implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, is partially-ordered if the variable is an inline variable that is not an implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, and otherwise is ordered.

So, an initialization of instance of `std::ios_base::Init` is ordered, and initialization of `B::a` is partially-ordered.

> 3. Dynamic initialization of non-local variables `V` and `W` with static storage duration are ordered as follows:
>
> 3.1. If `V` and `W` have ordered initialization and the definition of `V` is appearance-ordered before the definition of `W`, or if `V` has partially-ordered initialization, `W` does not have unordered initialization, and for every definition `E` of `W` there exists a definition `D` of `V` such that `D` is appearance-ordered before `E`, then ...
>
> 3.2. Otherwise, if the program starts a thread other than the main thread before either `V` or `W` is initialized, it is unspecified in which threads the initializations of `V` and `W` occur; the initializations are unsequenced if they occur in the same thread.
>
> 3.3. Otherwise, the initializations of `V` and `W` are indeterminately sequenced.

3.1 and 3.2 don't apply. So we have indeterminately sequenced initializations.

You can make `B::a` a non-`inline` static variable or somehow force `std::ios_base::Init` initialization before using `std::cout`, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785008):

```
struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::ios_base::Init init;
};
```