Is there any difference in the initialization order between such two cases?
Consider this example:
#include <iostream>
struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout<<"hello" << std::endl;
    }
};
inline A a;
int main() {
}

This example causes the program segment under Clang 15, instead
#include <iostream>
struct A {
    A() {
        std::cout<<"hello" << std::endl;
    }
};
static inline A a;
int main() {
}

This example successfully prints hello. In such two cases, the specifier static, IMO, shouldn't affect the initialization order of std::cout and the variable a, the initialization order of them are both indeterminately sequenced, right?

Standard streams are pretty special and runtimes usually go to great pains to ensure they are among the first things to be initialized in any program. While in theory the order may be indeterminate, in practice it most definitely isn't.

Looks like a Clang bug to me, from the first glance. I don't see anything on cppreference that would explain the difference.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62738001/5754656 (It's a std::ios_base::Init object being created when you #include <iostream> with ordered initialization), so inline A a = (std::ios_base::Init{}, A()); is enough to make sure the streams are initialized

Be careful to include C++ std headers before any other and code should work. cout and cin use an ancient trick to overcome the fiasco: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter

What are you trying to achieve by having an inline global variable?  Also, what is a static inline variable?

In short, the difference you're seeing is possible, but it's a pure coincidence.
In practice, if you use just static without inline, it would work.
Detailed explanation
Firstly note [basic.start.dynamic] p1:

Dynamic initialization of a non-block variable with static storage duration is unordered if the variable is an implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, is partially-ordered if the variable is an inline variable that is not an implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, and otherwise is ordered.

Both inline A a and static inline A a have partially-ordered initialization.
Because #include <iostream> appears before the declaration of a in either case, the declaration of std::cout is appearance-ordered before a in both cases, but not the definition.
The initialization of std::cout takes place via an instance of std::ios_base::Init with static storage duration (see [iostream.objects.overview] p5) and with ordered initialization.
libstdc++ has a (see <iostream>, line 80) declaration:
// For construction of filebuffers for cout, cin, cerr, clog et. al.
// ...  
static ios_base::Init __ioinit;

std::__ioninit has ordered initialization, as mandated.
Let's look at the consequences in [basic.start.dynamic] p3:

Dynamic initialization of non-block variables V [std::cout] and W [a] with static storage duration are ordered as follows:

(3.1) If V and W have ordered initialization and the definition of V is appearance-ordered before the definition of W, or if V has partially-ordered initialization, W does not have unordered initialization, and for every definition E of W there exists a definition D of V such that D is appearance-ordered before E, then [...]
(3.2) [...]
(3.3) Otherwise, the initializations of V [std::cout] and W [a] are indeterminately sequenced.


std::__ioinit doesn't have partially-ordered initialization and a doesn't have ordered initialization, so surprisingly, their initialization is indeterminetely sequenced despite the definition of std::__ioinit being appearance-ordered before that of a.
static in this context just gives your variable internal linkage, which has no impact whatsoever in terms of wording.
The fact that it solves your issue is purely a coincidence.
Also note that static inline makes basically no sense for variables, and you could just use static instead.
Solution
In practice, if you remove inline and just keep static, your code would work.
In that case, you would have static ios_base::Init __ioinit followed by static A a.
std::__ioinit would be appearance-ordered before a and both would have ordered initialization, so the initialization of std::__ioinit would be sequenced before that of a.
If you insist on using inline variables, you can also add another std::ios_base::Init to your code:
inline std::ios_base::Init init;
inline A a;

Both init and a are have partially-ordered initialization and init is always appeareance-ordered before a.

It is mandatory that including #include<iostream> behaves as if it defined a static storage duration object of type ios_base::Init. The initialization of ios_base::Init is guaranteed to initialize the standard streams (and is the only way to do so). The definition of std::cout musn't matter (i.e. it has to have constant initialization in practice).

@user17732522 that's all true, but unfortunately, there is no guarantee that __ioinit is initialized before our own inline variables.

@JanSchultke I think we should discuss the order between the instance of ios_base​::​Init and a, as per iostream.objects#overview-3 and iostream.objects#overview-5

@xmh0511 what do you mean by that? The answer does discuss that and cite these paragraphs. The of initialization is indeterminately sequenced or sequenced depending on whether inline is used or not.
